# Xcode cannot run using the selected dvice

Tags: xcode

i post this question because none of the solutions posted to
already existing threads helped for me.

today morning everything worked fin, i pressed on the Run-Button and
my iOS-Simulator stated out of Xcode showing my implemented App.

few hours later it shows this error-message:

"Xcode cannot run using the selected device. No provisioned iOS devices
are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with 
a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an
iOS simulator as the destination."

My Targets iOS SDK is 6.1
Under Summary i chose as Device an iPad (as before)
Under Summary i chose 6.1 as Deployment Target.

I have no "real" iOS Device at home so i always used the simulator.
As i said, since today afternoon not working.

what could be the prblem?

Comment: This question is a bit confusing.  Do you have an iPad device to test with? If so, which iOS version is the iPad running? Or are you getting this message when trying to run under the simulator?